# Show custom button on a specific profile

Tags: custom-button, profile, page-layout, standardlayout

I have a custom button on a standard salesforce page and I want to show this custom button to only few specific profiles, how would I do that? since this is a custom button on a standard page.

Comment: Not sure that you can do that by the profile other than by having different page layouts.

Comment: @Nick Clone the layout and remove the button and assign to profiles .